# How did Maz Kanata acquire Luke's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, the-force-awakens

Hidden away in a storage room beneath Maz Kanata's Castle, Rey finds Luke's first / Anakin's second lightsaber

[image]

We last saw that weapon when Luke's hand was severed on cloud city, causing the hand and lightsaber to fall down the same chasm Luke later falls down.

How did it get from where we saw it last to eventually end up in Maz Kanata's Castle?

Comment: It sucks that so many answers to so many *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* are just "We don't yet!".

Comment: if by "sucks" to mean "that's how trilogies work"

Comment: I think she explicitely says in the movie that this is a "good question" that she will not answer now. So to me it basically mean that we can't know before episode VIII / IX

Comment: The real question, though, is if someone has Luke's severed hand in a jar somewhere. Because if they do, he can regenerate without changing his appearance.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Can we get a meta-crisis Luke also?

Comment: We do know that they will be making "Anthology" movies - so much like 'Rogue One' will tell things leading up to 'A New Hope', there will likely be a movie elucidating the events between Hope and Empire. In fact, she pretty much says as much "that's another story, for another time"

Comment: People who voted to close this or didn't can you please vote to reopen my question? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111121/in-star-wars-the-force-awakens-how-could-the-lightsaber-that-rey-picks-up-be Thanks @AndresF.

Comment: There's no way this is going to get resolved sanely but this question clearly ought to stay open, as it has a good, correct, accepted answer. *If* there is a dupe, the latter one is a dupe of this one, though I'm not convinced that's true (JMFB's is explicitly allowing for non-canon answers.)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield thank you, please feel free to __vote to reopen__. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**We don't know.**

As commented above, she explicitly evades this question from Han in the movie.

We do know from *Empire* that Luke's hand was cut off and the light saber was presumably intact, simply lost somewhere in Cloud City or perhaps even Bespin. The original trilogy's protagonists were too busy trying to escape the empire to go back and look for it. It's possible Vader had a few storm troopers search it out and Maz got it from his possessions, but for now, this falls squarely into the category of information that we are not meant to know at this time.

Comment: When Maz says "That is a good question for another [time]" you can almost mentally fill in the word "movie" :)

Answer (score 5):

It couldn't have been lost on Bespin because Bespin is a gaseous planet that only has a thin stratum of habitable atmosphere.  It would have to be recovered from somewhere in Cloud City.  It would have just been destroyed if it had fallen into the planet.

Answer (score -3):

My theory:- maz had a vision that a new jedi would arrive and claim lukes light saber in order to bring peace to the galaxy. Because of this, maz used her connections to find the saber and keep it safe away from the the dark side. Rey turned up and felt the force calling to her. However maz was not to know that Rey would refuse to take it.