# In Star Wars: "The Force Awakens," how could this lightsaber have turned up where it did?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

In *The Force Awakens*:

> Maz Kanata tells Rey that the lightsaber she just picked up and had visions from belonged to Anakin and Luke and now it's hers.

The lightsaber that Luke got from Obi-Wan Kenobi in *A New Hope* was lost/destroyed when Luke fought Darth Vader in Star Wars: *The Empire Strikes Back*.

In *Return of the Jedi* Darth Vader compliments Luke on building a new lightsaber and tells Luke that his skills are now complete.

How could that possibly be the lightsaber that Anakin used originally, and that was then passed on to Luke, when that lightsaber no longer exists?

Writers notes, director's notes, interviews, cast interviews, etc. are welcome. Thanks.

[image: Rey receiving lightsaber]

Comment: You may want to spoiler tag your question and make the title more ambiguous.

Comment: This is not a dupe. My question was not how did Maz acquire this weapon. My question is how does that lightsaber even exist. It was intact when he cuts luke's hand off, and falls down the shaft. But you see what happens when luke falls. It's going down a shaft that's at the bottom of a city in the clouds. It's cool though, dupe it, and I'll be back in a few months. :)

Answer (score 30):

It was lost not destroyed. We saw what happens to Luke but he was a fairly big foreign object picked up by the Cloud City filtering system. However the fate of the lightsaber might be different:

Legends [says](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_second_lightsaber) this

> The lightsaber, still clutched by Luke Skywalker’s hand, had become lodged in one of Cloud City’s lower air shafts and eventually was recovered by a maintenance drone.

So it could have ended up anywhere.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Where did you get that quote from?

Answer (score 23):

We do not know the answer yet:

> Maz Kanata says in the film: 'a good question, for another time'

Answer (score 13):

The [Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary) explictly states that Luke's lightsaber was recovered from within Cloud city. Since the city is floating in mid-air above a gas giant planet, we can reasonably assume that instead of falling into the airducts and then being expelled from the bottom of the city (like Luke), it simply came to rest at the bottom of the main reactor shaft.

[image]

Quite how it ended up in Maz's possession is something that hasn't yet (and possibly won't ever be) explained.

Answer (score 12):

**We don't officially know where Maz got the lightsaber yet, but we can guess.**

We've officially established the following:

We don't know where Maz Kanata obtained Luke's old lightsaber.

Kylo Ren is using a lightsaber of ancient design, inexpertly crafted, in his service to Snoke.

About thirty years have passed since the lightsaber was lost.

Kylo Ren claims that the lightsaber is *his* in the movie.

There is a distinct possibility that Luke Skywalker had found his old lightsaber in the ~30 years since RotJ and Ben was trained with it. When Ben then killed off the new Jedi order, he could have discarded it (or it could have been taken from him).  This would then put it closer to Maz's reach.

Interesting aside: this theory, if true, means that this lightsaber was used in the killing of **two** sets of young Jedi.

Comment: I think Ren claims it as his merely by right of inheritance.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 That doesn't explain why he'd recognize it by sight.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 he could have seen a picture of it.

Comment: Or the Force told him it was important, so he claimed it as his own.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 What right of inheritance would he have? Ben was the son and heir of Leia and Han, neither of whom ever actually owned the sword. Or are you supposing Ben/Kylo considers that Luke only dishonestly had the sword, and that it should by rights come directly to himself from Anakin/Vader?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not proposing that there is a strict, formal inheritance that leaves the sword in his hands, but rather that it is his family's sword and he sees himself as the most legitimate member of the family to lay claim to it.

Comment: Kylo reverences Darth Vader... He talks to a crushed helmet of his!!! Imagine just how bad would he want to get a hand on Vader's former lightsaber.

Comment: @LcSalazar Still not buying that he'd recognize the lightsaber on sight without ever having been exposed to it before. My money's still on him having used it in training.

Comment: @Axelord this is great; there is nothing irrefutable in this idea and it would support the bigger narrative unfolding. Also to support your point: Kyle Ren strains with his assertion that the saber is _his_. He is very familiar with it