# Which Luke Skywalker lightsaber is in TFA?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

Luke lost his first lightsaber, which was also his dad's lightsaber, and then he constructed a new lightsaber. Then in "The Force Awakens" Maz tells Rey that that lightsaber belonged to Luke's father, and then Luke, and now calls to her?

Is it the lost lightsaber from "The Empire Strikes Back",  the new one that Luke made himself, or was it Darth Vader's lightsaber?

Comment: Technically the other question is "What was the path of lightsaber X at location Y to location Z" and this question is "Was that lightsaber A, B or C?"

Comment: @CreationEdge - The titles of both questions were edited (by users other than the OP), which obscures the similarities. But the basic question is the same. See e.g. this text from the other question body: “How could that possibly be the lightsaber that Anakin used originally, and that was then passed on to Luke, when that lightsaber no longer exists?”

Comment: @Adamant "Is it the lost lightsaber from "The Empire Strikes Back", or was it the new one that Luke made, or was it Darth Vader's lightsaber?", pretty clear A/B/C question there, present in the original.

Comment: Seeing how Bespin is a gas giant with a surface gravity identical/comparable to Earth, in other words _Bespin is Saturn without rings_, I think the only valid explanation would be the lightsaber "bullshitted" its way into Maz's hands. Diving into a gas giant is kind of forbidding pressure-wise, let alone finding a lightsaber-sized object inside it. Alas, Sci-Fi is not necessarily always physically accurate or even logical, especially not when Lucas is involved. Does it have to be?

Comment: @Damon: you are assuming the lightsaber was vented out into Bespin's atmosphere, like Luke was.  Who is to say it doesn't get stuck in some pipe/vent somewhere before it reaches that far, as suggested by [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111131/42754).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, because you can _see_ how Luke's hand and the lightsaber drop down as the latch opens (with him hanging from his left hand). To me that looks like "gone forever".

Comment: @Damon: I watched the scene just now, and I do not see anything that looks like the lightsaber. When Vader cuts off Luke's hand, the camera doesn't show his hand falling down the shaft, so we don't see where it goes. And when Luke falls outside, the only thing shown falling into the atmosphere looks more like a white box, like maybe a pouch or something was shaken off of Luke's utility belt.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one lightsaber that was passed on from Anakin to Luke, and that is the lightsaber that Obi-Wan took from Anakin at the end of "Revenge of the Sith" and gave to Luke in "A New Hope", which Luke then lost at Cloud City in "The Empire Strikes Back".

We do not (yet) know the story of how the lightsaber ended up in Maz's pocession after that:

> ```
>                       MAZ
>        I've had this for ages...
>
>       MAZ'S CASTLE - TREASURE ROOM - DAY
>       Maz opens the box -- holds out the lightsaber to Finn:
>
>                       MAZ
>        Kept it locked away.
>
>                       HAN
>        Where'd you get that?
>
>                       MAZ
>        **A good question for another time.**
>
>                       (TO FINN)
>        Take it! Find your friend!
> ```

To compare, you can see Luke receive Anakin's lightsaber in this scene:

And here's a clear image of Maz Kanata handing the same one to Rey:

[image]