# How was this notable weapon possibly retrieved?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

Okay, so Maz talks about how that’s Luke’s lightsaber and his father’s, before him. And also explains why Kylo Ren wanted it so badly.

But how’s that even possible...?

1. In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Luke loses his arm **and** the lightsaber when he’s fighting with Darth Vader in Cloud City. That’s the lightsaber Obi-Wan had given Luke in *Star Wars: A New Hope*, telling him it was his father’s.
2. In *Return of the Jedi*, when Luke hands himself over to the stormtroopers, one of them gives Luke’s saber to Darth Vader (saying it’s the only thing/weapon he had on him). Anyway, during that conversation, Vader points out “I see you have constructed a new lightsaber.”

   - Also, it was green (not blue) if I recall correctly, but I’ll let that slide for now.
3. Later, when Darth Vader loses his arm, he also loses his lightsaber.

   - (Arms, Lightsabers and Giant Vents do not, a good combination, make.)

So the lightsaber Maz talks about could be Luke’s. But it definitely wasn’t Darth Vader’s or Anakin’s.

Have I missed something or was one of the chopped-arm-lightsabers *not* lost down a vent?

Answer (score -1):

Anakin Skywalker is Luke's Father. Anakin

> becomes Darth Vader

So that lightsaber is

- Anakin's 2nd lightsaber
- Luke's first lightsaber
- > is used by Finn and then Rey in Ep. VII

See: [When does Luke's lightsaber first appear in the Star Wars saga?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111503/when-does-lukes-lightsaber-first-appear-in-the-star-wars-saga/111600#111600)

At this point **we don't know** exactly how that lightsaber got from falling down in Cloud City in Ep. V to be

> in Maz Kanata's Castle in Ep. VII.

See: [How did Maz Kanata acquire Luke's lightsaber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111023/how-did-maz-kanata-acquire-this-weapon?lq=1)