# How did they recover Luke's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

In Episode V Luke drops his lightsaber from cloud city into Bespin, a gas giant. In VII it is seen recovered on Takodana held by Maz Kanata. How did anyone find and retrieve it?

Comment: See also: [How did Maz Kanata acquire Luke's lightsaber?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111023/5184)

Answer (score 0):

As Maz says in TFA, it is "a story for another time" (probably not the exact quote).

We do not know at this point, and must wait for episode VIII, according to Maz.